# How to build a 2 x 2 grid of buttons using jQuery Mobile?

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I am trying to build a 2x2 grid in jQuery Mobile using the following code:

```
<div class="ui-grid-a">
<a class="ui-block-a" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" href="#france">France</a>
<a class="ui-block-b" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" href="#india">India</a>
<a class="ui-block-a" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" href="#uk">UK</a>
<a class="ui-block-b" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" href="#usa">USA</a>
</div>
```

I would expect to get France and India on one row and UK and USA on the second row. In practice, I'm getting the four buttons on four different rows i.e. one on top of each other.

I've experimented a bit with CSS and found out that if I change the width of the A elements to, say, 49%, I do get two buttons per row except that the buttons are not centered on screen (i.e. they only take 2 x 49% = 98% of the screen space and 2% are left on the right). If I force the width of the A to be 50%, I get the initial behaviour i.e. one button per row.

Anyone has a solution? Thanks.

Comment: I've found a solution: use CSS to make the margin of the A elements 0px and they render fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally one should Create separate div elements for blocks and have the buttons enclosed inside those div elements

Answer (score 4):

You need to wrap them in a `ui-block-?` div, Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/CZLcR/31/

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="content">
        <div class="ui-grid-a">
            <div class="ui-block-a">
            <a data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" href="#france">France</a>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b">
            <a data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" href="#india">India</a>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-a">
            <a data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" href="#uk">UK</a>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b">
            <a data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" href="#usa">USA</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've also noticed that you can make the margin of the A elements 0px using CSS and they render fine.